# App doesn't show up anything on simulator after building static Table View

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm learning how to make `static` `table views` from this url (http://manenko.com/2014/12/16/how-to-create-an-input-form-using-uitableview.html)
I've followed everything it says and also as instructed, I delete all the methods from inside the class including the `numberOfSectionInTableView`, `numberOfRowsInSection`, and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. The app failed to build.
If I reinsert the methods without changing anything, The app works but didn't show anything, just an empty canvas. How do we solve this problem?
It's the first time I use storyboard to design my app. Thanks!

here's the full code

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var labels: [UILabel]!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    updateWidthForLabels(labels)


}

func calculateLabelWidth(label: UILabel) -> CGFloat {

    let labelSize = label.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: CGFloat.max, height: label.frame.height))

    return labelSize.width
}

func calculateMaxLabelWidth(labels: [UILabel]) -> CGFloat {

    return labels.map(calculateLabelWidth).reduce(0, combine: max)
}

func updateWidthForLabels(labels: [UILabel]) {

    let maxLabelWidth = calculateMaxLabelWidth(labels)

    for label in labels {

        let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: maxLabelWidth)

        label.addConstraint(constraint)
    }
}
```

Comment: have you connect it's delegates and connection correctly>]

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: Can you get the custom UITableViewCell? in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Have you set the custom class for  tableview controller (in storyboard) ?

Comment: If you're doing it programmatically, are you instantiating the right view controller?

Comment: I have connected its delegates and connection @NitinGohel

Comment: Here's the code @HardikShekhat

Comment: Yes I have set the custom class for tableview @raki

Comment: Yes I have initiated the right view controller, in fact, there's only one view controller. @Polis

Answer (score 1):

Check the delgates for the tableview,It may help you

[image]

Comment: I have checked the delegates and it's connected. Still it won't show.

Comment: Is it the `numberOfSectionInTableView`, `numberOfRowsInSection`, and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` are called

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I forgot to uncomment the close curly brackets "}"
And it works marvellous. Thank you for your answers, guys!